# Problems in integration and uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying real ananlysis and have trouble in solving the following problems. Can anyone help me?

Prove or disprove

(1)
Let $f$ be an analytic function such that $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-a)^n$ for $|x-a|<r$ with $a$ being a limit point of ${x\in R: f(x)=0}$. Then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in (a-r,a+r)$.

(2) $f(x)=(sinx+cosx)^{100}$ defined in $R$ is uniformly continuous function.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with? At least part (2) is pretty trivial.